# Subgroup of elements of order at most $2^{m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, contest-math

The problem A5 in Putnam 2009 reads as follows:

> Is there a finite abelian group $G$ such that the product of the
>   orders of all its elements is $2^{2009}$?

The answer is **No**. I am reading the official solution [here](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnam/-pdf/2009s.pdf). The solution starts by observing that if such group existed, it would be a 2-group. By structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, we may write

$$G\cong\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (\mathbb{Z}/2^{i}\mathbb{Z})^{e_i}$$

for some nonnegative integers $e_1, e_2, ...$ all but finitely many of which are $0$. I am having trouble understanding the step that immediately follows:

> For any nonnegative integer $m$, the elements of $G$ of order at most
>   $2^m$ form a subgroup isomorphic to  $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}
>  (\mathbb{Z}/2^{\min(i, m)}\mathbb{Z})$$

I can see that the elements of order at most $2^{m}$ forms a subgroup. But I don't see why this subgroup must be isomorphic to the group $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}
 (\mathbb{Z}/2^{\min(i, m)}\mathbb{Z})$. Can someone shed light on this matter? Perhaps even show an explicit isomorphism if possible?

I appreciate any input.

Comment: A more general question as to the possible products of the orders of all elements of a finite group has been raised at MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141774/what-natural-numbers-can-be-considered-as-the-product-of-orders-of-elements-of-a

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Awesome! Thanks for the link. Looks like a very difficult problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at each factor individually.

The subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/2^i\Bbb{Z}$ if elements of order at most $2^m$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2^{\min(i, m)}\Bbb{Z}$, because, as a subgroup of a cyclic group, this must be cyclic, and if $ i < m$ then all $2^i$ elements have order at most $2^m$, otherwise only $2^m$ of them do because $\Bbb{Z}/2^i\Bbb{Z}$ is cyclic, so the subgroup is generated by a single element $g$, and, because $g$ has order $2^m$, the subgroup generated by $g$ must have $2^m$ elements (if $g$ had order less that $2^m$, then all of the elements of the subgroup would also have order less than $2^m$, but clearly, if $i\ge m$, $\Bbb{Z}/2^i\Bbb{Z}$ has an element of order exactly $2^m$).

Since the order of an element of a product of groups is the LCM of the orders of it's projections onto the factors, an element of order at most $2^m$ in $G$ is given by simply choosing an element of order at most $2^m$ from each factor, which is exactly the desired isomorphism.